# If statement inside Wordpress Contact Form 7 E-mail Template

Tags: wordpress, html-email, shortcode, contact-form-7

I'm trying to edit E-mail 2 in Contact Form 7 Wordpress plugin. I have an Option tag

```
[salutation](Mr, Mrs), in German Language – [anrede] (Herr, Frau)
```

So, in E-mail 2 template I have to write 2 different texts like:

```
Sehr geehrter Herr
Sehr geehrte Frau
```

The first one is when the [anrede] option is 'Herr', and the other one is when the [anrede] option is 'Frau'.

```
if ([anrede] = "Herr"){
<p>Sehr geehrter Herr</p>
}
else if([anrede] = "Frau"){
<p>Sehr geehrte Frau</p>
}
```

Thank you in advance,
Jon Kraja

Answer (score 3):

and if statement isn't needed, seems to me is much easier as follows and w/o plugin conditional fields.

Generate a select field with your values

--> [select anrede "Herr|geehrter" "Frau|geehrte"]

Take care, that a  pipe symbol (|) is between the values as shown above. 
Note: only the left side of the select field is shown on contact form!; the right side is NOT shown and always hidden. BUT you can choose both values with different codes on your Mail:

If you would put left side of value into your mail, use [_raw_anrede] - means "Herr" or "Frau" is given out.
If you would put right side of value into your mail, use [anrede] - means "geehrter" or "geehrte" is given out.

With this you may have a correct salutation depending on "Herr" or "Frau" is choosen at the select field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hook 'wpcf7_before_send_mail'.

```
function hsc_cf7_submit_update_email($cf){
    $formID = $cf->id();
    $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if (!$submission){
        return;
    }
    
    if($formID == 'ENTER FORM ID'){

        $submitData = $submission->get_posted_data();

        $mail = $wpcf7->prop('mail_2');
        $mailBody = $mail['body'];
        if($submitData['anrede'][0] == 'Herr'){
            $mail['body'] = "<p>Sehr geehrter Herr</p>";
            $wpcf7->set_properties( array("mail_2" => $mail)) ;
        }elseif($submitData['anrede'][0] == 'Frau'){
           $mail['body'] = "<p>Sehr geehrte Frau</p>";
            $wpcf7->set_properties( array("mail_2" => $mail)) ;
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'hsc_cf7_submit_update_email' );
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with contact form 7 alone, but you can do it with [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/).

Comment: Yes, I have installed this plugin before, but it is for Conditional Fields. As I described above, I want to make conditions inside HTML E-mail template in order to change my custom text, I don't want want any condition in my Contact Form Fields.

Comment: If you implement a hidden field with that "shows" when chosen "Herr" with the value "Sehr geehrter Herr" you can set up the email to contain that salutation. Some trickery is needed, but it works! :-)